# What is a good strategy to deal with lots of engineers turtling on the other team?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Now that the Engineer update has come, there will be lots of Engineers building up everywhere.  How should this best be handled?

Comment: What's "turtling"?

Comment: Yep - since this game is driven by physical points (capture points, intelligence points, cart checkpoints) in most of the gamemodes, "turtling" is often effective.  It can make for quite the stale-mate if done to an extreme.

Comment: @ChrisF like a turtle hinding behind a carapace. Each and every engineer in a TF2 game can build a defensive turret and thus turtle a point

Comment: Kind of fun for Question #1 on the site.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Lots of medics with lots of ubers on high-damage-dealing classes.  Demomen, if they are any good, usually work best against a sentry farm — stickies are perfect for this job, the usual problem is living long enough to deploy and detonate enough of them.

Heavies or pyros can also be effective, **if they can get close enough** (short range for a heavy, point-blank for a pyro) without being overwhelmed by the knockback before they can do damage. The medic should lead the uber combo in (particularly if the partner is a heavy) — he's faster, so he can absorb the knockback better.

If at all possible, back the uber team(s) up with as much raw firepower as you can muster — the aim is to either overwhelm the engies' ability to repair stuff, take out the engies directly, or take out dispensers.  Soldiers are good for this support role, as they can place well-aimed damage from behind the uber.  Demos can support well, too — their indirect fire can damage engies and dispensers without having to kill the sentry first.

Sending a spy in to sap just before or during the uber(s) can be a good idea, too.

Comment: Don't forget that crits don't do extra damage to buildings. That kritzkrieg might be more useful on a heavy standing behind the uber.

Comment: @Whatsit: interesting, I didn't know that, can you provide a source?

Comment: @Whatsit If you uber the heavy and kritz him the engie is gone in about 1 second, leaving no one to repair the sentry.

Comment: @Oak: http://tf2wiki.net/wiki/Critical#Notes

Comment: @Corv1nus: Any half-decent engineer will be crouched behind his sentry. Bullets don't penetrate the sentry so the engineer shouldn't be hit.

Comment: @Whatsit - Crouching doesn't make them 100% hidden.  A heavy's bullet spray will wipe them out.  I've done it at least 100 times. Also, crockets and crit stickies will wipe him out.  I've done that 100s of times too.

Comment: An uber pyro can also be very effective at taking out a nest.

Comment: Uber pyro using the Homewrecker. +100% Damage against buildings.

Comment: remember: while critz dont do extra damage against buildings they can be devastating to the engineer behind them.

Answer (score 26):

Unfortunately, twiddling your thumbs behind your own base isn't going to win your team the round. If there are that many Engies, Spies will probably be ineffective.

Grab yourself some medics and frontline (or take 'em from behind) forces like Heavies, Soldiers, or Demomen, uber, and advance. Side tip : as you advance, have your progress reinforced by your own engineers setting up on newly-won terrain behind you. This will help your new ground to hold out longer.

Class updates will always create all-of-a-sudden influlxes of the respective classes, but just remember their strengths and weaknesses, and don't feel too overwhelmed.

Comment: I've always felt that Soldiers are a bad choice for ubered structure destruction. Pyros and Heavies have continuous damage output, while Soldiers can only fire a few shots before reloading. Thus, Soldiers should hit the Engie hardpoint at range, while the Pyros and Heavies get up close and personal with an uber.

Answer (score 18):

A lot of engineers usually involves a lot of teleports.

As a spy, alert your team about your intentions and go to sap the teleports entrances. These will cause the engineers move the focus out of the sentries and your team should be able to put them down. 1 uber or 2 could help. ;)

Answer (score 14):

As a long-time engineer player, I'd say my sentry has been killed by a soldier or demo more than anything else.

Spies are useful in hectic situations but not when there are multiple alert engineers, and ubers are useful but require careful coordination and are very limited.

I say, go with corner-edging soldiers and sneaky demos. A big enough concentration of them can just cause so much damage the engineers can't keep up.

Also, any source of crits (buff banner, krit medic) can be a great help. It doesn't do extra damage to the sentry but it can definitely do some serious damage to the engineer healing it.

Comment: I cannot say how many times a crit rocket has killed me while repairing my sentry.

Answer (score 8):

For pre-update senties, they will always shoot at the closest enemy. Run an uber up front to take all the sentry fire, and let the rest of your team stand behind and focus fire on the sentries without getting shot (By the sentries at least). Soldiers work well for this, as they can straight-shoot the sentries from a distance. Direct-hit especially so. Just remember you need at least two soldiers per sentry or the engineer can out-repair the damage.

Watch out for pyros air-blasting you with this method. Kill them first if you can.

Whenever ubers attack sentries, the medic should run ahead of their buddy. This allows the medic to take the brunt of the knockback and allows both players to get closer. This is especially important when there are multiple sentries, because the accumulated knockback can push a demo or heavy back beyond their effective range.

Answer (score 6):

It's not just the job of spies, medics, and heavy-hitting classes, everyone can pitch in to help take down a sentry!

**Scout**

As a scout, you can Bonk! in and draw the fire of the Sentry.  As long as you're the first thing it sees, un-Wrangled sentries will target you and not the rest of your team.  Even if they DO wrangle, you can still act as a distraction to the rest of the team (Spies especially love a wrangled sentry nest).  Might even get in the Engine's face and force him to accidentally shoot himself.

**Sniper**

Yes, you too can help take out a Sentry nest!  In fact you have the most important job of all - Taking out the Engineer!  Assuming you can get a good line of sight, one shot to his head is all it takes.  And when he's dead, there's nothing to stop you from charging a shot and picking off his unguarded sentry either.  The Machina can help damage Engies that hide behind their sentry, but for unattended sentries, the Sydney Sleeper charges up VERY fast.  For a full breakdown, go [here.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14374/fastest-way-to-kill-a-sentry-gun-with-a-sniper-rifle) If all else fails, you can always throw a Jarate grenade to soften the Engie & his pals.

**Engineer**

You have the pistol, which like a Scout's pistol can take down minis and level 1s at a distance.  But you've also got a Wrangler, which if you can get your sentry into position can tear through another Engie's sentry, assuming he doesn't catch on.  The best way you can help your team though is by building up a teleporter, so that they can get to and take down the other team's Sentry.

Of coures, this is only if you insist on playing these classes...otherwise switching to a higher damage-output class, a medic, or even a spy might be more useful.

Answer (score 4):

As a soldier, a Direct Hit is great vs any Engineers nest, particularly in large open areas where you can outrange them. The low splash damage of the Direct Hit is negated by the fact that sentries don't move, but most importantly **firing 4 Direct Hit rockets without delay will destroy a sentry even if 1 engineer is repairing it** (though 2 will likely repair through the damage). The only trick is making sure no one kills you while you are firing.

Comment: Sniping a sentry with 4 normal rockets just outside the range of the sentry usually works just as well. Obvious counter is the wrangler in both cases, as it allows the engy to shoot back and gives the sentry a shield.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Yes, but a direct hit is faster and more reliable. Also, a direct hit can kill in just 2 shots (I believe) if the sentry is not being repaired.